# Python script won't work on Autokey

Tags: python, html, linux, html-entities, autokey

I'm trying to make a html entities encoder/decoder on Python that behaves similar to PHP's `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`, it works normally as a standalone script:

**My input:**

```
Lorem &Aacute;&Eacute;&Iacute;&Oacute;&Uacute;&Ccedil;&Atilde;O&Aacute;&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute;&ccedil;&atilde;o @#$%*()[]&lt;&gt;+ 0123456789
```

`python decode.py`

**Output:**

```
Lorem ÁÉÍÓÚÇÃOÁáéíóúção @#$%*()[]<>+ 0123456789
```

Now if I run it as an **Autokey** script I get this error:

```
Script name: 'html_entity_decode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 454, in execute
    exec script.code in scope
  File "<string>", line 40, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/scripting.py", line 42, in send_keys
    self.mediator.send_string(keyString.decode("utf-8"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's the script:

```
import htmlentitydefs
import re

entity_re = re.compile(r'&(%s|#(\d{1,5}|[xX]([\da-fA-F]{1,4})));' % '|'.join(
    htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint.keys()))

def html_entity_decode(s, encoding='utf-8'):

    if not isinstance(s, basestring):
        raise TypeError('argument 1: expected string, %s found' \
                        % s.__class__.__name__)

    def entity_2_unichr(matchobj):
        g1, g2, g3 = matchobj.groups()
        if g3 is not None:
            codepoint = int(g3, 16)
        elif g2 is not None:
            codepoint = int(g2)
        else:
            codepoint = htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[g1]
        return unichr(codepoint)

    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        entity_2_chr = entity_2_unichr
    else:
        entity_2_chr = lambda o: entity_2_unichr(o).encode(encoding,
                                                           'xmlcharrefreplace')
    def silent_entity_replace(matchobj):
        try:
            return entity_2_chr(matchobj)
        except ValueError:
            return matchobj.group(0)

    return entity_re.sub(silent_entity_replace, s)

text = clipboard.get_selection()
text = html_entity_decode(text)
keyboard.send_keys("%s" % text)
```

I found it on a Gist https://gist.github.com/607454, I'm not the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the backtrace the likely problem is that you are passing in a unicode string to  keyboard.send_keys, which expects a UTF-8 encoded bytestring. autokey then tries to decode your string which fails because the input is unicode instead of utf-8. This looks like a bug in autokey: it should not try to decode strings unless their are really plain (byte)sstrings.

If this guess is correct you should be able to work around this by making sure you pass a unicode instance to send_keys. Try something like this:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection()
if isinstance(text, unicode):
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
text = html_entity_decode(text)
assert isinstance(text, str)
keyboard.send_keys(text)
```

The assert is not needed but is a handy sanity check to make sure html_entity_decode does the right thing.

Comment: I got the decoding/encoding direction the wrong way around. I've updated my answer to match the expectation from send_keys: it requires a utf-8 encoded string, which you are currently not getting because  clipboard.get_selection is returning a unicode string for you (when run under autokey).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the the output of:

```
clipboard.get_selection()
```

is an unicode string.

to solve the problem replace:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection()
```

by:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection().encode("utf8")
```